# Cannot validate form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate various fields present in a form using Javascript. But, the fields are not getting validated. The null fields are accepted and email patter is not matched.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateform(){
            var username=document.myform.username.value;
            var password=document.myform.password.value;
            var course=document.myform.course.value;
            var x=document.myform.email.value;
            var atposition=x.indexOf("@");
            var dotposition=x.lastIndexOf(".");

            if (username==null || username==""){
                alert("Name can't be blank");
                return false;
            } if(password.length<6){
                alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
                return false;
            }
            if (course==null || course==""){
                alert("Course can't be blank");
                return false;
        }
            if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length){
                alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:"+atposition+"\n dotposition:"+dotposition);
                return false;
            }
    </script>
    <br>
    <title>Insert Operation</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="Insert.php" onsubmit="return validateform()">
    <div id="textbox">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    Course:<input type="course" name="course"><br><br>
   <input class="btn" type="Submit" value="Insert" name="done">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'd look at your developer console; this is a typographical error. Use a code editor with pair matching and you'll see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: And how is this a php question?

Comment: I noticed you're present since you removed the php tag, per my question above earlier. So, have you figured out where the problem is? as in what's "missing"? Did you put this in a code editor? Or would you rather remain silent and my telling you what you missed or someone else? TBH, this question doesn't give any value to the Stack library of questions, it's a mere typo. Don't be shy, you can answer back here and ask. However, I rather "you" figure it out so you'd of "learned" from it (your mistake).

Comment: No I have been trying since a long time. I didn't get where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Just add another brace `}` in here `}
    </script>`. Looking at the developer console, would have shown you this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.